# livequery doesn't bind after a DOM insertion

Tags: javascript, jquery, bind, jquery-events, livequery

I don't understand why `livequery` doesn't bind the event, but I have to use `.click`.
This is just an example, which might also use the `.click()`, but in the real code I'm forced to use `livequery`.
Does anyone know why `livequery` isn't working?

```
function bind_remove(comment){
    var id = comment.attr('comment_id');    
    comment.find(".remove").livequery("click", function(e){    
        $.post("/deleteComment", {id: id}, function(response){
            comment.remove();
            comments = comments_container.find('.comment');
        });    
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){    

    var comments_container = $('#comments_container');
    var comments = comments_container.find('.comment');

    comments.each(function(){
        bind_remove($(this));
    });
    
    $(".submit_button").livequery("click", function(e){
    $.post("/newComment", {text: textarea.val()}, function(response){                    
        comments_container.last().append($(response).fadeIn('slow',function(){                    
                comments = comments_container.find('.comment');
                bind_remove(comments.last());                            
            }));
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: I tried both version 1.4.4 and version 1.5.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a random id to the last comment, then I selected it with $('#myid'), not using 'last()'. Then I bind it and started to work

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
comment.find(".remove").livequery("click", function(e){
```

with this

```
comment.find(".remove").live("click", function(e){
```

Comment: Could you post more code? You cut it right in the middle of a function.

Comment: more code are about 1000 rows...I can try to change the existing code to make it more understandable... Read it now! ;)